# Run whole selenium project in docker (Gradle + Selenium + java + junit + docker)

Tags: java, docker, selenium, gradle, automated-tests

My current project is java selenium (with selenide framework) auto-tests with gradle and junit.

Now, I want to wrap my whole project to docker container, to make it possible to run it on other machines using only docker.

As I see it:

- User run my docker image
- Image have installed java + chrome + selenium + gradle
- Project tests launched within container.
- (optional) image shares test results outside image (or I can connect to container and take a look at them).

What am I suppose to do?

A saw a lot of tutorials about browsers in containers, selenoid, etc.(which is cool).

But I can't find a solution for my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest to run tests as `docker-compose` multi-container application.

It will have 2 services in `docker-compose` as i see it:

- `browser` - based on selenium Chrome browser [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome)
- `tests` - based on custom image extending `java` base [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/). Custom image `Dockerfile` should have `gradle` installed and tests jar file built in it.

Tests should drive Chrome browser using `RemoteWebDriver` initialized as below (note `browser` hostname where remote Chrome is listening).

```
public void createChromeDriverForRemote(){
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://browser:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
}
```

See quick start [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#quick-start)

Comment: Thank you! It's worked for me properly exactly how I want.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. Create a docker image that has Java, Chrome, selenium, gradle, junit, etc
2. Once you have the image, run it on your local on any port example: 4444
3. Switch to RemoteWebdriver

```
public static String remote_url_chrome = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remote_url_chrome), options));
```

4. Run the test now